Wait for html2canvas to finish, before showing "successful" message
(Repost from serverfault)
I'm pretty new to JavaScript development.
I have a PHP/HTML webpage where users can edit things and once they're done, they click on "Save" and it saves changes to the database. This works well, but what I implemented, is html2canvas to save a rendered image of the current state, to display it on another page.
My problem is: Rendering and saving takes about 15 seconds right now until the image file is saved. If users close their tab before this is done, of course the rendering breaks. So I decided to display a message "Please wait for rendering", that closes once the rendering is done.
But I can't manage to wait until the rendering is done - I have read lots about promises, async, await and stuff but yet I don't fully understand that functionality.
Here's my code:
const saveButton = document.getElementById('saveButton');
saveButton.addEventListener('click', saveChanges); 
function saveChanges() {  
    // here is the code for saving data to database ...
    // then the image will be rendered  
    console.log('Start image generating')
    showSaveMessage('Öffentliche Ansicht wird generiert...'); // This creates a message box
    // setTimeout is needed, because otherwise somehow, the rendering is missing texts etc.
    setTimeout(() => {
        html2canvas(document.getElementById('map'), {
            onclone: function(document) {
                // do some CSS changes before rendering
                });
            },
            scale: 2,
            useCORS: true,
        }).then(canvas => {
            console.log('Starting to convert');
            const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
            fetch('sources/saveimage.php', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({ imageData: imgData })
            });
            console.log('Conversion done');
        });
    }, 200);
    hideSaveMessage(); // This closes the message box
}

Currently, the message box is closed immediately after opening it, so it doesn't actually wait for rendering and saving the image. I also tried adding a .then after fetch, but it closes the message within 1-2 seconds, while PHP needs 10-15 seconds to actually finish the image saving.
My PHP is pretty easy:
<?php

$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
// error_log($data);
$image = explode('base64,',$data); 
file_put_contents('images/glencore/rendered.png', base64_decode($image[1]));

?>

Maybe some of you are kind enough to solve this and explain to me :-)

You never wait for your html2canvas to finish, just move the hideSaveMessage call to a then attached to your fetch( /saveimage.php )  and it should display until it's complete? So bascially fetch('sources/saveimage.php', {...}).then(hideSaveMessage) Right now showing the message, starting the process and hiding it are tasks that get executed immediately after each other.

It seems that your goal is to prevent the user from leaving the page until the PDF creation is complete.
To achieve this you can use the beforeunload event to show a warning alert to the user that a process is still running, and will be affected if they leave the page too early. Unfortunately you can't amend the text shown in the notification, but hopefully it should be enough of a prompt to tell the user to wait.
Here's a demo of how to implement that. If you click the 'Save' button, then try and click the link to navigate away from the page, the browser will ask you to confirm the action. When the PDF generation is complete the user will be free to navigate away as normal.


const showSaveMessage = msg => document.querySelector('#message').textContent = msg;
const hideSaveMessage = () => document.querySelector('#message').hidden = true;
let pdfGenerationInProgress = false;

const saveButton = document.getElementById('saveButton');
saveButton.addEventListener('click', saveChanges);

function saveChanges() {
  console.log('Start image generating')
  showSaveMessage('Öffentliche Ansicht wird generiert...');

  pdfGenerationInProgress = true;
  setTimeout(() => {
    // generate the PDF here...

    console.log('Conversion done');
    pdfGenerationInProgress = false
  }, 5000);

  hideSaveMessage();
}

window.addEventListener('beforeunload', () => {
  if (pdfGenerationInProgress) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.returnValue = '';
  }
})
<div id="message"></div>
<button id="saveButton">Save PDF</button>

<a href="https://google.com">Leave page...</a>



It's worth noting that this is by no means a fool-proof solution. A better approach, if possible, would be to generate the file server side, so that the user is free to navigate your site as they please while the file is generated then notify them when the file is ready to access - either via websockets, or emailing them a link to download.

Hey, this works pretty well in the first run, thanks!
Can you provide an example of how to render it serverside? I tried different approaches with firefox/chrome cli tools, but I did not get it done because of issues with a virtual display etc.
It's just a Rocky Linux CLI-server with no monitors attached.

I generally use IronPDF to generate PDFs on the fly, but there's lots of others. If you have a Google for 'Generate PDF in [your server-side language here]' it should get you some results

Hi, unfortunately I don't want a PDF but an image file generated. I don't really find solutions for this.

Apologies - my mistake. In that case Google 'Html to image [your server-side language here]'
